# What is the fastest equivalent to `str.lstrip()` that does not copy the string?

Tags: python, string

In Python, the `str.lstrip()` method returns a copy of the string with leading characters from the set removed (or leading whitespace removed, if the set is not provided):

> `str.lstrip([chars])`
> Return **a copy of the string** with leading characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

Let's suppose I have a large input string (assume hundreds of megabytes) that consists of runs of non-whitespace data interleaved by runs of whitespace:

```py
instr = ''.join(
    (''.join(random.choice(string.whitespace) for _ in range(random.randint(0, 1e3))) +
     ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.randint(0, 1e3)))
     for _ in range(int(1e5)))
)
```

I have a parser for the data, but this parser

1. does not accept leading whitespace, and
2. stops at the trailing whitespace, returning the last parsed position.

The naive method of parsing the whole string would be to call `str.lstrip()` on the remaining substring, then call the parser on the result, update the substring and loop. However, this would copy the substring unnecessarily on each iteration.

The parser is able to accept an optional starting position, but that interface is undocumented and I'd prefer not to use it.

---

How do I avoid the copy in `str.lstrip()` and the substring (slice) operator?

Comment: There is a [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) type which can give you a "view" on some bytes, but it's really only really similar to a string when you've got ASCII data. As soon as you have any high utf-8 (> 1 bytes codepoints), this "poor-man's string view" starts to get very complicated. What type does your parser expect? What is the minimal interface it needs to work? Can you give it a sequence and a start/end index into the sequence to work with?

Comment: An idea (might be limited by space) would be to try and cast to a list of characters, filtering out whitespace, and running your parser on the entire resulting join of the list. The advantage here is you'd be able to separate your 'processing' into stages, rather than having the cleaning happening during your parsing.

Comment: Additionally, you could try: one pass to get whitespace indices, second pass call parser on the valid ranges. Since strings are immutable, the way to "not copy" would be to access the string as a singleton.

Comment: Slicing also makes a copy, so that's not going to help. Does your parser accept a start position, or does it always start at the beginning of the input?

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, I did not know that. I thought that slicing returns an immutable view, which is apparently wrong.

Comment: @wim The parser can accept a starting position, but it's an undocumented interface and I'd prefer not to use it. As I've been just made aware, string slicing also makes a copy, so the task is even more complicated than I thought. The string is guaranteed to be ASCII, though.

Comment: At the very least, `your_string.split()` will make a list of parts for you, only doubling the memory usage and omitting all the whitespace. Does your parser need a string or `Iterable`? If it can work with an iterable of chars, you can make an `iter(your_string)` and advance it as much as you want any time, meaningful parts will be consumed by parser, and you'll handle the rest.

Comment: can you create an iterator and call next() until you have stuff to work with?

Comment: Maybe use `for match in re.finditer(r"\w+", s): yourparser(match[0])` which is only creating strings per word as you iterate them?